# Can there be acceleration without force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

$$F=\frac{dp}{dt}=ma+\frac{dm}{dt}v$$

if force equals zero then $ma=-\frac{dm}{dt}v$. So there can be acceleration without applying force. Doesn't it disobey the $1^\text{st}$ law of Newton?

Another thing is what is the frame of reference for the $v$ in expression $\frac{dm}{dt}v$. Because $v$ would be different in different frame of reference. But applied force doesn't depend on the frame of reference.

Comment: can you describe a scenario where dm/dv is not zero?

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question:

> Another thing is what is the frame of reference for the v in expression $\frac{dm}{dt}v$.

Centre of mass.
$$F_{ext}=v_{rel}\frac{dm}{dt}+m\frac{dv}{dt}$$
where $F_{ext}$ is the net external force on the body, $v_{rel}$ is the relative velocity of the escaping or incoming mass with respect to the center of mass of the body, and v is the velocity of the body.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like circular reasoning, but as far as I know in classical mechanics, what we have *so far observed in real experiments* is that *acceleration of a mass is the consequence of applying external force onto the mass*, i.e. you cannot have acceleration without a force.

On an unrelated note, mass may not be necessary to create force. Some clever scientists developed *optical tweezers* wherein they used light (a massless particle, but has momentum) to hold very small objects, making the objects levitate.

Answer (score -1):

The dm/dt term indicate that mass of the object is not constant. So it is changing . Assuming that law of conservation of mass to be true , if the mass of the object increase or decrease , it must mean that mass is exchanged between that object which you are concedering and some other object. Only way for doing so is an inelastic colision . And in inelastic colision Force can never be 0 . So this indicate that if you assume F=0 , mass should remain constant. In that case dv/dt is 0.

Comment: Not true.  Consider a rocket ship in free space.  When it exhausts gas, the rocket is accelerated forward.  This is variable mass system because of the explusion of fuel.  No collisions are necessary.

Comment: Do you even know how rockets move or what is thrust. As the fuel combusts, it  releases gas molecules moving in all directions .  Some of those gas molecules collide with the rocket and push it forward while others are freely expelled without any colision.

Comment: Don't gases exert pressure?

Comment: The collision of the gas molecules with the rocket is an elastic, not inelastic, collision.

Comment: What you are doing is considering the rocket and it's fuel collectively as an object and the exhaust gas as the "other object" that is responsible for change in mass. What basically happens is that fuel changes into exhaust gas.  Recall what is colision . Then recall what is inelastic colision . Then think deeply what happens in the process of change of fuel molecules to exhaust gas molecules and then say isn't it inelastic colision?

Comment: As the exhaust is expelled it provides a momentum kick to the rocket. If this were inelastic then no net momentum would be imparted in this case.  If you stand on a frictionless surface with a basketball, and throw the basketball you'll find yourself moving as a result. This is what is happening.  Collisions have nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: I said you to recall what is colision first?

Comment: People teach about contact forces and colision but never say the what is the root cause of contact forces

Comment: Wherever there is interaction between 2 particles , there is colision

Comment: Also note that in the case of throwing basketball , there is no change of mass involved

Comment: Draw a box around the person with the ball.  As soon as they throw the ball their mass changes.   Without this sort of accounting you couldn’t have dm/dt=0 in the original post.

Comment: In cases where mass is conserved you can never have dm/dt=0 if you account for all the mass.

Comment: You say "draw a box around the person with ball. As soon as they throw the ball their mass changes" . Do you mean that before throwing the ball, the person and ball are 1 identity and after throwing they separate into 2 , indicating change of mass of the box ? If that is what you mean then that is simply a perfectly inelastic colision.  It is like a particle separating into 2 particles and kinetic energy changes after that separation. The source of this extra kinetic energy is always potential energy  .

Comment: In case of rocket example potential energy of fuel molecules converts to kinetic energy of exhaust gas molecules. In case of basketball example the source of kinetic energy is chemicle reactions inside the body that stretch muscles of the person to throw the ball

Comment: That is exactly what I said at the begining